# How can i define DEBUG when the build type is debug?

Tags: meson-build

I want to pass "-DDEBUG" to the C++ compiler when the build type starts with "debug", something like this:

```
if meson.build_type().starts_with('debug')
  add_global_arguments('-DDEBUG', language : 'cpp')
endif
```

However there is no `meson.build_type()`, so I get this error message from meson:

```
Meson encountered an error in file meson.build, line 5, column 23:
Unknown method "build_type" in object.
```

How can I get the build type? Or is there a different way to define `DEBUG` in debug builds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if get_option('buildtype').startswith('debug')
  add_project_arguments('-DDEBUG', language : 'cpp')
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work on meson 0.63.0, instead I did this, per the [FAQ](https://mesonbuild.com/FAQ.html#should-i-check-for-buildtype-or-individual-options-like-debug-in-my-build-files):

```
if get_option('buildtype') == 'debug'
  add_global_arguments('-DDEBUG', language : 'cpp')
endif
```